# USB Device that acts like a printer

Tags: arduino, driver, esp8266, usb-device

Our client uses some third party software and devices for their internal work. They print 600 pages per shift and now they wanted to eliminate paper usage without changing their existing systems.

There are `LaserJet` printers that are connected with desktop `PCs` and `thermal` printers that are connected with some small `handheld devices` which read data from third party cloud server.

[image]

**Wanted Solution:**

I was wondering if we cloud make some kind of programmed wifi enabled USB device (lets say `ESP8266`) that acts like a printer for PCs and handheld devices. When this device is connected it should be detected as printer and what it does is simply accepts prints and send it to our cloud server.

I know how to deal with all the cloud communications. What I just wanted to know is how to make my device detected as printer and access the file? Do I need to burn some kind of printer drivers in it or what.

- Desktop OS: Windows 7
- Handheld Device OS: Linux
- Printers: HP LaserJet
- Thermal Printer: Black Copper
- Printer Ports: USB A

**EDIT**

I know that there are various apps for print to pdf but we cannot use them because we dont have rights to directly copy files from these systems. External storage is disabled and we cannot even copy files and send over internet from this restricted pc. So we have only option to read that is coming to printers.

This is something similar that I want: **USB Printer Emulator**
https://www.pclviewer.com/resources/capture/identity.html

Comment: There is already software that emulates a printer to generate a PDF file, no need for a physical device at all.

Comment: Welcome to EESE! However you have not provided enough detail to be able to meaningfully answer your question. You have not identified interfaces, protocols, devices, or anything that can narrow down the space of possibilities. As it is, this question will be closed for being either too broad or off-topic. See  [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: @Hearth I know that there are softwares and windows 10 have buitin option to save files as pdf. As I mentioned in question we have very limited access we can just change printers

Comment: @EdgarBrown updated my question

Comment: Take a look at the data that goes to the printer, then reconsider.  Thermal printers drivers send what amounts to a picture to printer - you would have to make images from the data and use character recognition on it if you need to, say, read an invoice number out of it.  Inkjets the same, multiplied by the number of color tanks.  Postscript printers are your best bet - but I doubt the existing label printers are postscript.

Comment: You can't make your device just be recognized as "a printer."  It must be recognized by the manufacturer's driver as **their** printer, and you must properly communicate with their **proprietary** protocol over USB, and you must process their **proprietary** format.

Comment: Have you tried a google search for "usb printer emulator"? This is one of the first hits: https://www.pclviewer.com/resources/capture/print2usb.html

Comment: @EdgarBrown yes I checked this one. This is somewhat I want to build

Comment: There _are_ commercial products that take a literal "print stream" that assumed it was ending up at a line printer and redirect it for software manipulation somewhere else. This is used in places where there are some legacy systems no one wants to crack open and change but at the same time they don't want to keep printing reams of wide-carriage tractor-feed paper. But, as far as I know, these are minimally hardware based, other than knowing how to pull data off a serial or parallel port. As pointed out in the comments, how to make sense of the bytes in the print stream is the challenge.

Comment: @jdv this is the exact situation with us. They are not that legacy systems but lets say they are restricted by vendors.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to violate your agreement with the vendors. You are only supposed to **print** documents but you want to save them in the cloud instead, is that right?

Comment: @Elliot not violating any agreement its just those systems are restricted by vendors. Its factory's own data, there isn't any legal challenge

Comment: You said "we don't **have rights** to directly copy". That sounds like you are trying to do something that you are not supposed to do, according to some agreement with the vendor. Why not just contact the vendor and ask them to change to a PDF print driver or email the documents to you?

Comment: Yes because we have very limited access to those computers but there aren't any legalities that you are concerned about. It's not my own project it's one of our company client's work and its a big erp type system for factory which they dont want pay hefty amount for new module. So the question remains same is there anything that I can do to achieve this?

Comment: @UsamaAmjad Looks like you or your client don't have administrator rights on the system. But somebody must have them. Or is he dead and nobody has the password?

Comment: Yes they don't have administrator rights. They are third party computers that came with the erp. And they have another handheld device which is not windows but it works with most of the thermal printers in the factory.

Comment: *"We don't support what you want to do or allow you to install software on our product"* Doesn't mean OP is not allowed to look for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just purchase commercial products that do this. But rolling your own is possible. An ESP8266 would be too limited for this. It's meant to be a serial to wifi adapter with some extra GPIO. Instead, a computer with usb OTG or peripheral ports and linux using something like [USB Gadget Printer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_printer.txt) drivers that allows you to emulate a printer to the host computer. Obviously this will require some intermediate to advance coding to figure out. Once you have that set up, the print data can be forwarded, as it's likely in a standard PCL format. The time and skill needed should be compared to the commercial product cost.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408293/how-to-make-g-printer-usb-gadget-printer-work-in-raspberian-pi and https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/other-modules and https://forum.armbian.com/topic/1359-bananapi-installing-the-gadget-printer/

Comment: Of course, if your license with the vendor says "you cannot substitute the physical printer with a print to pdf solution" then don't do that. But I doubt it says that, any more than it says "don't scan the pages it prints out".